# CSS animation (greeting card open/close)

Tags: css, animation

I want to make CSS animation, based on this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/makzan/RE2JJ/). It fits me perfectly, however there are 2 things that I couldn't make. First - I want customize inner side of greeting card with two jpg files (inner-left, inner-right). Second - I want card open on click, and not click and hold.
I have tried to make it myself with trials and errors but was unsuccessful. If I include third file (inner-left) and make `backface-visibility: hidden` it's still not giving me required outcome. I have also tried to edit [this](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html) example but still couldn't make it. For css animation savvys it should be simple, I guess, so please can anyone help me out.
This is html that I am using,

```
<section class="container">
 <div id="card">
  <figure class="front"><img src="img_card/1.jpg"></figure>
  <figure class="inner-left"><img src="img_card/1-2.jpg"></figure>
  <figure class="inner-right"><img src="img_card/1-3.jpg"></figure>
 </div>
</section>
```

and the css part is in jsfiddle link.

Comment: In pure CSS, you will not be able to manage two states (card open , card closed). Here, the example uses the active state of a link, which is triggered  when a user clicks on the element. I'm afraid you will have to code some javascript to manage it.

Comment: I was thinking the same. But then, I have researched and found that with simple card flip effect (just with the flip on left axis) and by putting static third image on bottom of previous two, I will be able to simulate card open/close.

Comment: and yes, I want it to keep pure CSS. No js.

Comment: The second link in your question, makes use of JS. There is no "user has clicked before" in CSS, beside `:visited` on links, and you cannot *un-visit* a link by clicking again on it.

Comment: If you're situation doesn't permit you to use any js, you could use the "checkbox hack" to manage state https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: Thanks, guys! But until now you were all talking about my 2nd problem, what about 1st one (that has to do with card open and having inner-left and inner right). And for this, lets suppose that I am ok with "click and hold".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this without JavaScript by using a hidden checkbox, a label and the `:checked` and sibling (`+`) selectors.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danwad/92sp63L1/) which also has the inner-left and inner-right images.

Comment: Gosh, this is exactly what I need! did you code just now? Or was it ready and you just pointed me to the right fiddle? Anyway, thank you so much. How can I buy you a cup of coffee?

Comment: Just coded it now. Just a few modifications from the fiddle you linked to. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at something like this before and I think that might need to be achieved with either a javascript event that adds in a class on click to move your card to its open state.

https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

The above link goes to an example that shows a single card flipping but it should be close to the concept you are looking for

I hope that helps

Comment: another thing you could try is using the :checked pseudo selector or the :target pseudo selectors to toggle the state of your card.